# How to remove groups of observation with dplyr::filter()

Tags: r, data-manipulation, dplyr, subset

For the following data

```
ds <- read.table(header = TRUE, text ="
id year attend
1 2007      1
1 2008      1
1 2009      1
1 2010      1
1 2011      1
8 2007      3
8 2008     NA
8 2009      3
8 2010     NA
8 2011      3
9 2007      2
9 2008      3
9 2009      3
9 2010      5
9 2011      5
10 2007     4
10 2008     4
10 2009     2
10 2010    NA
10 2011    NA
")
ds<- ds %>% dplyr::mutate(time=year-2000)
print(ds)
```

How would I write a dplyr::filter() command to keep only the ids that don't have a single NA? So only subjects with ids 1 and 9 should stay after the filter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `filter` in conjunction with `base::ave`

```
ds %>% dplyr::filter(ave(!is.na(attend), id, FUN = all))
```

To obtain

```
    id year attend
 1   1 2007      1
 2   1 2008      1
 3   1 2009      1
 4   1 2010      1
 5   1 2011      1
 6   9 2007      2
 7   9 2008      3
 8   9 2009      3
 9   9 2010      5
 10  9 2011      5
```

Comment: yes, 1 and 9, I already corrected it.  Thanks, @Robert Krzyzanowski, this is exactly what i needed. I never seen ave() function used before, i'm glad I asked, learned something new.

Comment: I was waiting for 2 mins to pass to accept it :) thanks again!

Answer (score 29):

Or you could use:

```
ds %>%
group_by(id) %>% 
filter(attend=all(!is.na(attend)))
#Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
#Groups: id

#  id year attend
#1   1 2007      1
#2   1 2008      1
#3   1 2009      1
#4   1 2010      1
#5   1 2011      1
#6   9 2007      2
#7   9 2008      3
#8   9 2009      3
#9   9 2010      5
#10  9 2011      5
```

Comment: I like this one better, because it stays within dplyr and is shorter. Thanks!

Comment: And also `filter(!anyNA(attend))`.