# dplyr: How to filter groups by subgroup criteria

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, tidyr

My question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583152/how-to-remove-groups-of-observation-with-dplyrfilter), but the filter criteria is different.

```
> demo(dadmom,package="tidyr")

> library(tidyr)
> library(dplyr)

> dadmom <- foreign::read.dta("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/modules/dadmomw.dta")

> dadmom %>%
+   gather(key, value, named:incm) %>%
+   separate(key, c("variable", "type"), -2) %>%
+   spread(variable, value, convert = TRUE)
  famid type   inc name
1     1    d 30000 Bill
2     1    m 15000 Bess
3     2    d 22000  Art
4     2    m 18000  Amy
5     3    d 25000 Paul
6     3    m 50000  Pat
```

It is easy to pick out the family with mom's income >20000 using "incm" from the original table:

```
> dadmom
  famid named  incd namem  incm
1     1  Bill 30000  Bess 15000
2     2   Art 22000   Amy 18000
3     3  Paul 25000   Pat 50000
```

The question is: how do you do it from the "tidied" data?

Comment: `dplyr::filter(data, type == "m" & inc > 20000)`?

Comment: That returns only one row. I want the whole group (m & d).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add `group_by` and `filter` to the codes

```
#OP's code
d1 <- dadmom %>%
           gather(key, value, named:incm) %>%
           separate(key, c("variable", "type"), -2) %>%
           spread(variable, value, convert = TRUE)

 d1 %>% 
    group_by(famid) %>%
    filter(all(sum(type=='m' & inc > 15000)==sum(type=='m')))

#    famid type   inc name
# 1     2    d 22000  Art
# 2     2    m 18000  Amy
# 3     3    d 25000 Paul
# 4     3    m 50000  Pat
```

**NOTE:** The above will also work when there are multiple 'm's per famid (a bit more general)

For normal cases of single 'm/f' pair per famid

```
 d1 %>%
     group_by(famid) %>% 
     filter(any(inc >15000 & type=='m'))
 #   famid type   inc name
 #1     2    d 22000  Art
 #2     2    m 18000  Amy
 #3     3    d 25000 Paul
 #4     3    m 50000  Pat
```

Also, if you wish to use `data.table`, `melt` from the devel version i.e. `v1.9.5` can take multiple value columns.  It can be installed from [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
 library(data.table)
 melt(setDT(dadmom), measure.vars=list(c(2,4), c(3,5)), 
    variable.name='type', value.name=c('name', 'inc'))[,
    type:=c('d', 'm')[type]][, .SD[any(type=='m' & inc >15000)] ,famid]
 #    famid type name   inc
 #1:     2    d  Art 22000
 #2:     2    m  Amy 18000
 #3:     3    d Paul 25000
 #4:     3    m  Pat 50000
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of "any" and "all".  Are they efficient functions? I am asking because my actual data would have many groups, and many rows within the groups(though very regular, fixed number and sequence).

Comment: @Dong I think so.  How big is your dataset?

Comment: It is not big now.  ~(7x200k) --> (7x400k) after tidying.  For now it is ~100k groups -- like the ones from `group_by(famid)`, and 4 rows per group.  But both the width and length of the data will grow as I gather more experimental data.

Comment: @Dong Just a thought, if it gets big, wouldn't it be better to subset before `gather` ( haven't benchmarked though)