# Use group_by to filter specific cases while keeping NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to filter my dataset to keep cases with observations in a specific column. To illustrate:

```
help <- data.frame(deid = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 12, 12, 12, 12, 17, 17, 17),
               score.a = c(NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA))
```

Creates

```
   deid score.a
1     5      NA
2     5       1
3     5       1
4     5       1
5     5      NA
6    12      NA
7    12      NA
8    12      NA
9    12      NA
10   17      NA
11   17       1
12   17      NA
```

And I want to tell dplyr to keep cases that have any observations in `score.a`, including the NA values. Thus, I want it to return:

```
  deid score.a
1     5      NA
2     5       1
3     5       1
4     5       1
5     5      NA
6    17      NA
7    17       1
8    17      NA
```

I ran the code `help %>% group_by(deid) %>% filter(score.a > 0)` however it pulls out the NAs as well. Thank you for any assistance.

Edit: A similar question was asked here [How to remove groups of observation with dplyr::filter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583152/how-to-remove-groups-of-observation-with-dplyrfilter)
However, in the answer they use the 'all' condition and this requires use of the 'any' condition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove groups of observation with dplyr::filter()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583152/how-to-remove-groups-of-observation-with-dplyrfilter)

Comment: Suppose if `help$score.a[3] <- -1`, what would be the result?

Comment: Not sure I'm following your question, @akrun ... sorry. When I run that the 3rd row of score.a is -1

Comment: My question is that suppose one of the element in `score.a` for a particular group 'deid' is less than 0. Then would you select that group?

Comment: Yes. Correct. Essentially any observation in score.a and I want to keep that group. Although with the present data all observations are >= 0

Comment: So, your condition is not `all`, but `any`

Comment: So, my first solution should work.  I added the second solution as a bonus.

Comment: Yes! That worked... I ran the following code... `help %>% group_by(deid) %>% filter(score.a = any(!is.na(score.a)))`

Comment: But, that code is not checking the condition `score.a >0`  Check my update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
help %>%
      group_by(deid) %>%
      filter(any(score.a >0 & !is.na(score.a)))
#    deid score.a
#1    5      NA
#2    5       1
#3    5       1
#4    5       1
#5    5      NA
#6   17      NA
#7   17       1
#8   17      NA
```

Or a similar approach with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(help)[, if(any(score.a>0 & !is.na(score.a))) .SD , deid]
#    deid score.a
#1:    5      NA
#2:    5       1
#3:    5       1
#4:    5       1
#5:    5      NA
#6:   17      NA
#7:   17       1
#8:   17      NA
```

If the condition is to subset 'deid's with all the values in 'score.a' > 0, then the above code can be modified to,

```
setDT(help)[,  if(!all(is.na(score.a)) & 
         all(score.a[!is.na(score.a)]>0)) .SD , deid]
#   deid score.a
#1:    5      NA
#2:    5       1
#3:    5       1
#4:    5       1
#5:    5      NA
#6:   17      NA
#7:   17       1
#8:   17      NA
```

Suppose one of the 'score.a' in 'deid' group is less than 0,

```
help$score.a[3] <- -1
```

the above code would return

```
 setDT(help)[,  if(!all(is.na(score.a)) & 
           all(score.a[!is.na(score.a)]>0, deid],
 #   deid score.a
 #1:   17      NA
 #2:   17       1
 #3:   17      NA
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%group_by(deid)%>%filter(sum(score.a,na.rm=T)>0)
```

Comment: This would fail if `help$score.a[2] <- -0.2;
    help$score.a[3] <- 0.2; help$score.a[3] <- 0`

Comment: It is interesting, I changed to df%>%group_by(deid)%>%filter(sum(!is.na(score.a))>0), it work, but I don't know why.

Comment: But that is again not correct because `help$score.a[2:4] <- -0.2` in this case, all values are negative for deid `5`, but it sill returns that group.

Comment: df%>%group_by(deid)%>%filter(sum(!is.na(score.a))!=0)

Comment: I think it is not getting correct.  `df$score.a[11] <- -0.5`  It will still get the 17 group.