# Does dplyr filter always remove conditions that resolve to NA?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following dataset:

```
df_test_1 <- 
    data.frame(time = c(seq(20, 40, by = 5), NA))
```

Find all rows where `time` is greater than zero:

```
log_vec <- df_test_1$time > 0
```

such that:

```
> log_vec
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA
```

Consider filtering the original dataset on this condition in base R:

```
> df_test_1[log_vec, ,drop = FALSE]
   time
1    20
2    25
3    30
4    35
5    40
NA   NA
```

and the `dplyr` version:

```
> df_test_1 %>% filter(log_vec)
  time
1   20
2   25
3   30
4   35
5   40
```

Notice how the row with `NA` is returned in base R but not `dplyr`. Why is this happening, and is this behaviour always expected? I cannot find the documentation for this in the helpfile `?filter`. (Note, this has previously been observed in this question [Use group_by to filter specific cases while keeping NAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820684/use-group-by-to-filter-specific-cases-while-keeping-nas))

Comment: A similar question regarding `filter` was asked sometime back.  If i remember, the `filter` is designed to remove the NAs.  If you want the NA, you can use `|`, i.e. `df_test_1 %>% filter(log_vec | is.na(log_vec))`

Comment: right, thanks. I am just wondering why it is not documented anywhere.

Comment: For some functions (from the dplyr/tidyr), I had seen the function properties change with each new release i.e. that works before may not work now and viceversa.

Comment: that is most unfortunate :(